# How to pass multiple params to policy through Laravel route middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-authorization

I am trying to pass multiple arguments to my policy method. I am calling the policy as a middleware on my route. In my policy I need the authenticated user, the target group and the invitee. The authenticated user gets passed automatically by Laravel.

I wish to call the policy like this so it matches my other routes, but this always returns a 403 forbidden. I believe this happens because the middleware doesn't know which policy to use.

```php
Route::post('/{group}/invite/{invitee}', [GroupInvitationController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware('can:store,group,invitee');
```

If I use this line in my controller method instead of calling it from the route using middleware it works perfectly.

```php
$this->authorize('store', [GroupInvitation::class, $group, $invitee]);
```

My policy:

```php
class GroupInvitationPolicy
{
    public function store(User $user, Group $group, User $invitee) {
        return $user->isGroupAdminOf($group) || (
            $group->users->contains($invitee)
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny('User is already part of group')
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call the policy from the route middleware while also providing the policy with the correct parameters?

Comment: Try to remove `GroupInvitation::class` form `$this->authorize`, and tell me what happened.

Comment: I suspect you might have a problem because the method parameter is called `$invitee` but you're passing a route segment called `user`. Try changing your route definition to `/{group}/invite/{invitee}` then middleware to `can:store,group,invitee`. No idea if it will work, but I know matching names like that is a requirement for route model binding.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin If I remove the ```GroupInvitation::class``` the authorize function does not know which policy to use, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @miken32 I tried changing the names, but I think the first param after ```can:store``` points to the model name of which policy to use. No matter what I change, I am getting 403 forbidden.

Comment: At `AuthServiceProvider` in `$policies` add your model and policy, After you added you will not need to add `GroupInvitation::class`.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin My policy is already registered there and the ```$this->authorize``` function works fine. My problem is that I wish to call it from my routes file instead of using that line of code in my controller.

Comment: Yes, `store` is the policy, and the user is always passed, so `group,invitee` should be the other parameters passed. Not sure why it isn't working for you. Have you put debugging statements in your policy to see what parameters are being passed to the method?

Comment: @miken32 yes I tried, but even when I simply return true from my policy, I get 401 Unauthorized

Comment: But did you check what parameters were passed, or that the method was even called? Did it properly pass `$user`, `$group`, and `$invitee`? Your question presumes you can't "pass multiple params" to your policy. Have you verified that is the case?

Comment: @miken32 As I mentioned before, I always get the message: this action is unauthorized. There is no way for me check whether the parameters were passed because the policy method is never called. This is because the ```->middleware('can:store')``` does not know which policy to use. In that case Laravel always throws the unauthorized exception. So my question is how can I correctly call the policy from the route middleware while also providing it with parameters.